# Close out of WebviewScaffold or size flutterWebviewPlugin to fit parent widget

Tags: flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin, webviewscaffold

I am using flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.8 to open up a webview in my flutter app.
When I click on a button, a webview is opened.
I can do it in 2 ways.
`FlutterWebviewPlugin flutterWebviewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();`

1) `flutterWebviewPlugin.launch('https://google.com',withJavascript: true);`
The problem is that it opens google in a webview but it occupies the entire screen available. It doesn't respect the safearea or anything else defined in parent widget and not sure how to add a back button in the app bar.
And I can close it with flutterWebviewPlugin.close()

2)`Navigator.push<dynamic>(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => WebviewScaffold(
                url: 'https://google.com',
                withJavascript: true,
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: Text("Widget webview"),
                ),),),);`

This respects the safearea and I can also have an app bar with a back button but I am unable to close this. flutterWebviewPlugin.close() doesn't seem to work.

I also have a dispose method:

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.dispose();
super.dispose();
}
```

I need a way to close out of WebviewScaffold or size flutterWebviewPlugin according to parent widget. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve Statusbar overlapping in webview using flutter

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
          child: SafeArea(
          top: true,
          child: new WebviewScaffold(
            url: gisUrl,
            withZoom: true,
            withLocalStorage: true,
            hidden: true,
            initialChild: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: const Center(
              child: Text('Loading.....'),
            ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappbrowser (**EDIT**: it has been renamed to [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview)) 
allows you to add an inline webview

demo show inline webview with default project

[image]

full example code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MyInAppWebView(webUrl: "https://flutter.dev/",webRect: Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 300, 300))));
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded( child: MyInAppWebView(webUrl: "https://flutter.dev/", webRect: Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 300, 300),)),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}


class MyInAppWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  String webUrl;
  final Rect webRect;
  InAppWebViewController webView;
  MyInAppWebView({Key key, this.webUrl, this.webRect}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    InAppWebView webWidget = new InAppWebView(
        initialUrl: webUrl,
        initialHeaders: {},
        initialOptions: InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(),
        onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
          webView = controller;
        },
        onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
          print("InAppWebView.onLoadStart: $url");
          this.webUrl = url;
        },
        onProgressChanged: (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
          double prog = progress / 100;
          print('InAppWebView.onProgressChanged: $prog');
        });
    return Container(
      width: webRect.width,
      height: webRect.height,
      child: webWidget,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It has issue with keyboard